# Watermark a pdf document with itext 7 instead of iTextSharp

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, itext

This was my code for itextsharp which worked ok. It displayed "Quote Only" in the middle of each page in a pdf file.

```
 iTextSharp.text.Image img = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(Server.MapPath(@"~\Content\WaterMarkQuoteOnly.png"));

                PdfReader readerOriginalDoc = new PdfReader(File(all, "application/pdf").FileContents);
                int n = readerOriginalDoc.NumberOfPages;
                img.SetAbsolutePosition(0, 300);
                PdfGState _state = new PdfGState()
                {
                    FillOpacity = 0.1F,
                    StrokeOpacity = 0.1F
                };
                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(readerOriginalDoc, ms, '\0', true))
                    {
                        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
                        {
                            PdfContentByte content = stamper.GetOverContent(i);
                            content.SaveState();
                            content.SetGState(_state);
                            content.AddImage(img);
                            content.RestoreState();
                        }
                    }
                    //return ms.ToArray();
                    all = ms.GetBuffer();
                }
```

This is my new itext 7 code, this also displays the watermark but the position is wrong. I was dismayed to see that you cant add an image to the canvas but you have to add ImageData when the position is being set on the image. The image is also way smaller and back to front.

```
var imagePath = Server.MapPath(@"~\Content\WaterMarkQuoteOnly.png");

                var tranState = new iText.Kernel.Pdf.Extgstate.PdfExtGState();
                tranState.SetFillOpacity(0.1f);
                tranState.SetStrokeOpacity(0.1f);

                ImageData myImageData = ImageDataFactory.Create(imagePath, false);
                Image img = new Image(myImageData);
                img.SetFixedPosition(0, 300);                                            

                var reader = new PdfReader(new MemoryStream(all));
                var doc = new PdfDocument(reader);
                int pages = doc.GetNumberOfPages();

                using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    var writer = new PdfWriter(ms);
                    var newdoc = new PdfDocument(writer);

                    for (int i = 1; i <= pages; i++)
                    {
                        //get existing page
                        PdfPage page = doc.GetPage(i);
                        //copy page to new document
                        newdoc.AddPage(page.CopyTo(newdoc)); ;
                        //get our new page
                        PdfPage newpage = newdoc.GetPage(i);
                        Rectangle pageSize = newpage.GetPageSize();
                        //get canvas based on new page
                        var canvas = new PdfCanvas(newpage);
                        //write image data to new page
                        canvas.SaveState().SetExtGState(tranState);
                        canvas.AddImage(myImageData, pageSize, true);
                        canvas.RestoreState();
                    }
                    newdoc.Close();
                    all = ms.GetBuffer();
                    ms.Flush();
                }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are doing something strange with the `PdfDocument` objects, and you are also using the wrong `AddImage()` method.

I am not a C# developer, so I rewrote your example in Java. I took this PDF file:

[image]

And I took this image:

[image]

Then I added the image to the PDF file using transparency with the following result:

[image]

The code to do this, was really simple:

```
public void createPdf(String src, String dest) throws IOException {
    PdfExtGState tranState = new PdfExtGState();
    tranState.setFillOpacity(0.1f);
    ImageData img = ImageDataFactory.create(IMG);

    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
    PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(dest);
    PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(reader, writer);
    for (int i = 1; i <= pdf.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
        PdfPage page = pdf.getPage(i);
        PdfCanvas canvas = new PdfCanvas(page);
        canvas.saveState().setExtGState(tranState);
        canvas.addImage(img, 36, 600, false);
        canvas.restoreState();
    }
    pdf.close();
}
```

For some reason, you created two `PdfDocument` instances. This isn't necessary. You also used the `AddImage()` method passing a `Rectangle` which resizes the image. Also make sure that you don't add the image as an inline image, because that bloats the file size.

I don't know which programming language you are using. For instance: I am not used to variables that are created using `var` such as `var tranState`. It should be very easy for you to adapt my Java code though. It's just a matter of changing lowercases into uppercases.

Comment: Thanks. I don't want to change the size of the image which is 562 X 432 pixels, I just want to display it in the center. Well the image says "Quote Only" but it's shown upside down, that's what I meant.

Comment: It doesnt matter whether I say canvas.AddImage(myImageData, 0,0, false); or  canvas.AddImage(myImageData, 600,500, false); It is always displayed very tiny in the top left??

Comment: Bruno, this code in v5 img.SetAbsolutePosition(0, 300); Does not achieve the same thing as this canvas.AddImage(myImageData, 0, 300, false); Can you tell me how I achieve the same thing? Thanks.

Comment: That's strange. I'll try to reproduce that. Which version of iText 7 are you using? Normally, the size of the image shouldn't change (I looked inside the source code), and the two values you pass are x and y coordinates.

Comment: I am using 7.0.1.0 the community version. Thank you.

Comment: I was looking at 7.1.1.

Comment: I am now on 7.1.1.0 from nuget but its the same problem. :/ image is tiny in the top left corner.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie `var` = C#, it's called type inference: the compiler is supposed to be smart enough to figure out the type. This is supposed to give you less redundant and better readable code. Java is expected to have type inference in Java 10: https://blog.codefx.org/java/java-10-var-type-inference/

Comment: I thought I needed to copy the original pdf into a new version with the watermark. This works great.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie I avoid using 'var' on the lhs until I know what the type of the object on the rhs definitely is, then I replace it.  I only use 'var' in quickie/test/development programs when I can't be bothered to find or don't care what the object type is.  So it is useful, but I wouldn't leave it in my production code; it implies (to me) I don't know or can't be bothered to find out or understand the object type(s) I'm using and if THAT is the case ... then I shouldn't be coding anything in the first place!